# OpenVPN клиент не содержит опции “use default gateway on remote network”

Tags: openvpn

Я на **Windows 8.1**.

Пытаюсь последовать совету из https://superuser.com/questions/178674/setting-vpn-to-go-through-certain-ips-and-not-others/178675#178675

У меня есть сетевое соединение **TAP Adapter OAS NDIS 6.0** от **OpenVPN Technologies, Inc.**

Вот, что я вижу в секции **Параметры TCP/IP**:

[image]

Пожалуйста, объясните, почему у меня нет опции "use default gateway on remote network" и как я могу добиться того же результата

Answer (score 2):

Вы зря пытаетесь использовать ответ по настройке стандартного VPN для настройки OpenVPN.

В OpenVPN такие вещи настраиваются через конфиг-файл.

Вот опция для клиентского конфига:

```
redirect-gateway
```

При желании, эту опцию можно отправить с сервера всем клиентам:

```
push "redirect-gateway"
```

Comment: Павел, пожалуйста, подскажите, где находится этот клиентский конфиг?

Comment: @Boris где угодно. Зависит от того, как вы вообще запускаете OpenVPN на клиенте.

Comment: Это может быть *.ovpn файл из папки **C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\etc\profile** ?

Comment: Посмотрите содержимое этого файла - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aMSw2TMWNqMatVYa0PFtN6jsbgr-g_3nLaDyTHYVAJ4/pub - я там удалил ключи и заменил настоящий хост на 111.111.111.111

Comment: @Boris Ну да. А как вы еще можете перевести "OpenVPN client config file" в первой строчке?

Comment: @Boris вот только комментарий "# Automatically generated OpenVPN client config file" смущает. Вам надо найти генератор для этого файла.